# Перегрузка операторов для объединения массивов

Tags: массивы, перегрузка-операторов, c++

Подскажите, что не так с перегрузкой оператора.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class set 
{   const static int n=10;
    int mass[n];

public:
    int set_construct()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            mass[i] = 1 + rand() % 500;};
            return 0;
    }
     void print() 
     {
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
             cout<<mass[i]<<"  ";
     }

    set operator+(set rs)
    {
        const int x=2*n;
        set y;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            y.mass[i]=mass[i];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
            y.mass[i+n]=rs.mass[i];
        return y;
    }
};
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    set ob1;
    ob1.set_construct();
    cout<<"Первое множество\n";
    ob1.print();
    cout<<"\n";
    set ob2;
    ob2.set_construct();
    cout<<"Второе множество\n";
    ob2.print();
    cout<<"\n";
    set set_union;
    set_union=ob1+ob2;
    cout<<"Объединение множеств\n";
    set_union.print();
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает на return y необработанное исключение.

Answer (score 2):

Вы производите доступ к неаллоцированной памяти в `operator+`:

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    y.mass[i+n]=rs.mass[i];
```

Здесь `x == 20`, индекс `i` меняется от 0 до 19, индекс `i+n` меняется от 10 до 29.

Поскольку размер `mass` ровно 10 элементов, ваш код производит доступ за пределами разрешённой памяти, затирая случайные объекты. Вам повезло, что произошёл креш.

«Не так» здесь с дизайном вашего класса: для множества вы *не можете* рассчитывать на данные фиксированного размера. Поэтому уже объявление

```
const static int n=10;
int mass[n];
```

неверно и ведёт ко всем проблемам.

Кроме этого, вы ошиблись с индексами в `operator+`, но это уже второстепенная проблема.

А почему вы не используете `std::set`, а пишете велосипед?

(И да, вместо функций типа `set_construct` умудрённые опытом домохозяйки используют конструктор.)

Comment: Как исправить? Что мне сделать с 
const static int n=10;
int mass[n];

Такое задание - написать класс множество целых чисел.

Я совсем недавно начал изучать С++. Так что в число таких домохозяек не вхожу:)

Comment: Вы должны выделять память динамически, при помощи `new`. И не забудьте потом (в десткукторе, конечно) удалить её, если не планируете утечек памяти.

Comment: Это будет выглядеть как-то так?
.....
class set 
{   int n;
    int *mass;
 
public:
 set(){n=10;mass=new int[n];} 
 ~set(){delete[] mass;}
.....
Или нужно еще в каком месте изменить код?

Comment: Не совсем. Откуда взялась константа 10? Сколько элементов в вашем множестве? (И если больше 0, то какие?) Элементы массива лучше получать снаружи. Затем, в списке элементов массива не должно быть повторений. Вы это проверяете? Нет. Затем, при вычислении объединения множеств снова не должно быть повторений. Вы это учитываете? Нет.

Comment: 10 это количество элементов множества. Почему удобнее получать снаружи?для избежания повторений? С повторениями в объединении я разберусь после того как заставлю работать работать хотя бы так работать.

Comment: Ну, а какой смысл у множества, для которого вы не можете задать его элементы? :-)

Теперь смотрите. Для `operator+` вы должны:

* выделить память под новые элементы (сколько их будет?)
* скопировать туда элементы первого множества (их может быть не 10, а сколько угодно, понятно, почему?)
* скопировать за элементами 1-го множества элементы 2-го
Это для начала, потом разбирайтесь с повторениями.